# Amazon App Store More Apps Link

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I want to link to my Apps which are in the Amazon App Store.

The way described by Amazon is somehow not working anymore:

```
http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=com.amazon.mp3&showAll=1
amzn://apps/android?p=com.amazon.mp3&showAll=1
```

Results in:
`Your search did not match any products.`

([Linking To the Amazon Appstore for Android](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/community/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android.html))